# How to 301 Redirect Blogspot to Another Blogspot with Same Post?

Tags: blogger

I have a one blog (Old) which has good traffic. Now I have exported all posts to my other blog (New) and I want to redirect my Old Blog to my New Blog.

But when my customer opens `www.oldblog.blogspot.com/2015/02/Test-post.html` I want them to be redirected to `www.newblog.blogspot.com/2015/02/Test-Post.html`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Blogger does not provide any tools to support this.   And if someone gives you code to install to your old blog's template, then sooner or later oldblog.blogspot.com will be deleted as spam.

Your best bet is to

- Delete all current posts on www.oldblog.blogspot.com
- Make one new post which says "This website has moved, please visit
  www.newBlog.blogspot.com to find the content you were looking for"
- Go into www.blogger.com for oldBlog, and under Settings > Search
  preferences, set up a Custom Page Not Found re-direct, which also
  says "This website has moved, please visit www.newBlog.blogspot.com
  to find the content you were looking for"

I do not believe there is any way to do direct post-to-post redirections.

Answer (score 1):

When Server-side redirection is not supported, you can use `canonical` meta-tag in the `<head>` section of HTML:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/some-page-123" />
```

([*Read more*](https://puvox.software/blog/migrate-blogspot-301-redirect-to-another-site-using-meta-tag/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript in order to do so.

Go to the post you want to redirect, once you are there, switch to the **HTML** editor at the top-left of the page, and paste the following code:

```
<script>
// This will have a similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://webapps.stackexchange.com");
</script>
```

Change the url set on the - `window.location.replace(" ")` to whatever page(link) you want users to be redirected. Repeat the process to each post/page.